# Signals Declarations in VHDL

Tags: fpga, vhdl, components

In structural VHDL, is it acceptable to use signals declared with the same name in different components?

For example:

Component_1 uses a signal declared Temp_1

Component_2 also uses a signal declared Temp_1

These two components are both instantiated in the same higher top level source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signal names are isolated within VHDL modules.  So there is no "connection" between same-named signals between modules.  So it's perfectly acceptable to use the name "Temp_1" in different modules.  The only way to connect is via ports.

Comment: Thank you, I thought this was the case but just wanted to be double check.